# How do I filter an array of objects inside of an array of objects Using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below an array called `data`:

```js
const data = [
         {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: [{id:50 ,productname: 'Test A'}]},
         {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: [{id:60,productname: 'Test A'}]},
         {id:3 ,name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: [{id:70,productname: 'Test B'}]}
       ]
       
//I have an array of objects. Inside these objects, there is another array: tags. 
//My question is, how would I filter the multiple fields inside the data array 

 
//if I filtered by, e.g., a id:1, I'd receive the following returned:
   var output1 =   [{id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: [{id:50 ,productname: 'Test A'}]}]

  
// if I filtered by, e.g., a productname: 'Test A', I'd receive the following returned:
var output2 = [  {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: [{id:50 ,productname: 'Test A'}]}, {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: [{id:60,productname: 'Test A'}]}]

//I have tried the below code but it's not working 

    const filter = '1';
    //const filter = 'Test A';
    const Result = data.filter((item) => {
        return (
        item.id.toString().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||item.tags.indexOf(filter) > -1 
        );
    });
    
    console.log(Result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on an array of objects to check for a string value (eg: `'Test A'`) won't work, as your string doesn't equal an object within your array. Instead, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to specify the search logic using its callback and return `true` once you find a `product_name` that equals your `filter`:

```js
const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: [{ id: 50, productname: 'Test A' }] }, { id: 2, name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: [{ id: 60, productname: 'Test A' }] }, { id: 3, name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: [{ id: 70, productname: 'Test B' }] } ];

//const filter = '1';
const filter = 'Test A';
const Result = data.filter((item) => 
  item.id.toString().includes(filter) || item.tags.some(item => item.productname === filter)
);

console.log(Result)
```

I've also updated your `.indexOf()` call on your first string/id to use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), which is a more modern way to check whether your string contains a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can create respective functions for filtering the array. Say I've created two functions `filterByTag(key, value)` and `filterBy(key, value)`.

In the `filterByTag` function, provide two arguments `key` & `value`. Where the `key` is the object key inside the `tags` array.

This is similar to the `filterBy` function. The `fitlerBy` is applied directly to the `data` array.

```js
const data = [
  {id:1, name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: [{id:50, productname: 'Test A'}]},
  {id:2, name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: [{id:60, productname: 'Test A'}]},
  {id:3, name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: [{id:70, productname: 'Test B'}]}
];

const filterByTag = (key, value) => data.filter(item => item.tags.find(x => x[key] === value));
const filterBy = (key, value) => data.filter(item => item[key] === value);

console.log(filterByTag('productname', 'Test A'));
console.log(filterByTag('id', 60));
console.log(filterBy('id', 1));
console.log(filterBy('name', 'Product A'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `tags` is an array of objects inside each `product` object, we can make use of `Array.some` and find if any of the tag's `productname` is
matching with the required value that we are looking for

```js
const data = [
     {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: [{id:50 ,productname: 'Test A'}]},
     {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: [{id:60,productname: 'Test A'}]},
     {id:3 ,name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: [{id:70,productname: 'Test B'}]}
];

const getFilteredData = (data, value) => data.filter(datum =>
  datum.id.toString().includes(value.toString()) || datum.tags.some(tag => tag.productname.includes(value))
);

console.log(getFilteredData(data, 1));
console.log(getFilteredData(data, 'Test A'));
console.log(getFilteredData(data, 'Test B'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```